# How do I set delivery_mode on message using php extension AMQP with RabbitMQ?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I've set whole infrastructure meaning I've configure php with AMQP extension http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php. I've set up durable exchange and queue. Now I know I should publish message with delivery_mode = 2 (or equivalent to it in php) according to http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorial-two-python.html. I don't know if I can do that and if so I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$message = new AMQPMessage(serialize($object), array('content_type' => 'text/plain', 'delivery_mode' => 2));
```

This is using http://code.google.com/p/php-amqplib/, but I guess the native extension has a similar syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [my Amqp library](https://github.com/BraveSirRobin/amqphp) you can use the [documentation](https://github.com/BraveSirRobin/amqphp/wiki/Documentation) to get you started

Comment: You'd need to add an item in to the `$basicPublish` array in the Simple Producer demo: `'delivery-mode' => true/false`.  You can see the full set of available fields here: http://wiki.amqp.org/chatter:amqp-0-9-1-xml - the XML format shows you all commands and their arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Documentation was updated (on february 4th) and explains it all http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpexchange.publish.php

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Copy the content of the source THEN link to the source. If it was updated the day before you posted the answer, then obviously it's in flux and subject to change.